# Evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\left| 2t\cdot\text{sinc}^2(2t)\right|^2}\,dt$

Tags: integration

I have a question in solving the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\left| 2t\cdot\text{sinc}^2(2t)\right|^2}\,dt.$$

I know that you can use Parseval's Theorem to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{sinc}^4(kt) = \frac{2\pi}{3k}$ (I can provide the proof if you would like). While this might seem to help, I don't know that I can really use that fact with the $2t$ in the equation because you'll have to integrate by parts.

Is there another way that I could do this integral to make it easier? I feel like I might be overthinking it and this can be simplified down to something much more manageable.

Thank you so much for your help in advanced, I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: $*$ mean convolution or simple multiplication ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: wait $sinc$ not $\sin$... so you are asking for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 t)^4}{4 t^2}dt $

Comment: ok it corrected now

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts is enough. Our integral equals

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^4(2x)}{4x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^4(u)}{u^2}\,du=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{2\cos(u)\sin^3(u)}{u}\,du $$
but:
$$ 2\cos(u)\sin^3(u)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2u)-\frac{1}{4}\sin(4u)\,du $$
hence:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^4(2x)}{4x^2}\,dx = \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)\pi = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}.$$

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you did there. But just for clarification: in step 2 you did a u-substitution for $2x$, but I'm not sure how you expanded $sin^4(u)  = 2 cos(u) sin^3(u)$ in step 3?

Comment: Would you mind also explaining what identity (or identities) you did to simplify $2cos(u)sin3(u)=\frac{1}{2}sin(2u)−\frac{1}{4}sin(4u)du$? Thanks again for your answer and response!

Comment: @BillyThorton: in the first line I applied integration by parts. Obviously $\sin^4(u)\neq 2\cos(u)\sin^3(u)$ (even function/odd function), what is true is that $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{d}{du}\sin^4(u)=2\cos(u)\sin^3(u)$.

Comment: After that, the Fourier sine series of $2\cos(u)\sin^3(u)$ can be simply computed through De Moivre's formula, and we just need to exploit $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\text{sinc}(nu)\,du = \pi.$$

Comment: why do you add the pi at the end of the equation after your simplified it down to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2}sin(2u)−\frac{1}{4}sin(4u)du}{u}?$

Comment: @BillyThorton: because $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(4u)}{u}\,du=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{ \sin(2u)}{u}\,du = \color{red}{\pi}$$ as written above.

Comment: Ah okay. That makes sense. Thank you for your help, this really helped my understanding!

Comment: @BillyThorton: you're welcome :)